# Trying to randomly choose and reassign one of three variables in python

Tags: python, list, colors

New to python. I tried to assign three variables in a function, then try to reassign one of them at random to a different value, then be able to use all three later.

I tried to create a list containing the three variables, then make an outlier variable that is assigned to one of the three at random and then reassigned to a new value. However, the values it is returning are still all between 200 and 255.

```
import random

def newcolor():
  global logocolor, rvalue, gvalue, bvalue
  rvalue = random.randint(200, 255)
  gvalue = random.randint(200, 255)
  bvalue = random.randint(200, 255)
  colorvalues = [rvalue, gvalue, bvalue]
  outliercolor = random.choice(colorvalues)
  outliercolor = random.randint(0, 55)
  logocolor = (int(rvalue), int(gvalue), int(bvalue))

newcolor()
```

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Because you are not using outliercolor in your logocolor variable. Only outlier value is reassigned not others

Comment: What's the point of `outliercolor = random.choice(colorvalues)` if you just completely throw away the value in the next line? `outliercolor = random.randint(0, 55)` Also you didn't declare `outliercolor` as a global; you aren't returning the variable, so it's doing absolutely nothing in this function. If you are meaning to set something globally, you have to declare it as a global too, like you did with the others.

Comment: I believe OP is thinking in terms of "variables" as in "memory locations" while Python has names/references/bindings. `a = 5` does **not** create a memory location called `a` that you fill with `5`. It simply creates a reference called `a` attached to the object `5`. If you then do `a = "Hello"` what happens is that the `a` reference is moved to the object `"Hello"` but this leaves `5` unchanged. In your case you create a new reference to one of those objects and then you remove it again reassigning it to an other object. the objects themselves and original `*value` references are unchanged

Comment: after setting `outliercolor` do `colorvalues[random.choice(list(range(len(colorvalues))))] = outliercolor` then set `logocolor = tuple(colorvalues)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are confused about variable names and values in python. I suggest you read through this very useful post: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

You seem to have the misconception that `random.choice(colorvalues)` will choose one of the *variable names* you put in the list, and then assigning to that *variable name* will modify the original value. The list doesn't know about any of the variable names. It only knows about the *values* assigned to those variables.

Instead, you should pick a random *index* of the list to modify, and then modify that index.

You're also misusing global variables. You should instead *return* the values you want from your function, and assign them where you call the function.

```
def newcolor():
    rvalue = random.randint(200, 255)
    gvalue = random.randint(200, 255)
    bvalue = random.randint(200, 255)

    outliercolor = random.randint(0, 55)

    colorvalues = [rvalue, gvalue, bvalue]

    random_index = random.randint(0, 2)
    colorvalues[random_index] = outliercolor

    return tuple(colorvalues)

logocolor = newcolor()
```

Of course, this code can be reduced by creating the list directly instead of assigning color values to variables and then putting those into the list:

```
def newcolor():
    colorvalues = [random.randint(200, 255), random.randint(200, 255), random.randint(200, 255)]
    random_index = random.randint(0, 2)
    colorvalues[random_index] = random.randint(0, 55)
    return tuple(colorvalues)
```

Alternatively, you could simply create a list with two colors and one outlier color, and use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle the list around:

```
def newcolor():
    colorvalues = [random.randint(200, 255), random.randint(200, 255), random.randint(0, 55)]
    random.shuffle(colorvalues)
    return tuple(colorvalues)
```

Comment: That final implementation of `newcolor()` was going to be my suggestion as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

You actually haven't assigned newly generated color to any value in the list.

I suggest:

1. Not using global variables, it's not a safe practice
2. Splitting the logic into 2 functions: color generation and creating an outlier
3. If you need your original color to stay intact - you have to copy the list one way or another before adding an outlier

```
import random

def new_color():
    return [random.randint(200, 255) for _ in range(3)]

def add_outlier(color_values):
    outlier_idx = random.randint(0, len(color_values) - 1)
    outlier_color = random.randint(0, 55)
    
    new_color_values = [
        outlier_color if i == outlier_idx else color
        for i, color in enumerate(color_values)
    ]
    
    return new_color_values

color_values = new_color()
print("Original values: ", color_values)
print("Outlier added: ", add_outlier(color_values))
print("Original values still intact: ", color_values)
```

Output:

```
Original values:  [201, 242, 209]
Outlier added:  [201, 242, 1]
Original values still intact:  [201, 242, 209]
```